# Jenkins JMeter Selenium JUnit test does not display browser

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I have created a JMeter JUNIT Selenium test and have used Maven plugin to run that test. When I run my JMeter test from within the Java IDE it opens the browser. However, when I run the same test using Jenkins (running as a service) it does not display the browser. I was wondering if anybody is aware of this issue or have resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue above by running my tests in distributed mode i.e. deploying a Jenkins node to run JMeter tests on a separate node machine where Jenkins was run using JNLP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [run Jenkins service under account of the user which is currently logged in](http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html) like:

```
 Start -> Run -> services.msc -> find Jenkins service -> Properties -> Log On -> This account
```

and provide your username along with credentials. This way you will be able to see the browser.

However if you don't experience issues with your test it might be better idea to run Jenkins under [Local System Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) so your test [Selenium test could run headless](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins), in this case you will be able to continue working while tests are running to save time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri T for responding to my question. Am I right is thinking that in my case the test is running fine on Jenkins and it's just that the browser is not getting displayed?